# Mapping dynamic column names in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-columns

```
DECLARE @step VARCHAR(25) = '15';
DECLARE @COL VARCHAR(50) = step_col_@step;
UPDATE table_tblName SET @COL=<some value> WHERE <condition>
```

I have the above query where @COL is supposed to be dynamic i.e. step_col_1,step_col_2,step_col_3......step_col_18. How can I achieve this without If-else condition in sql server?

Comment: DECLARE @COL VARCHAR(50) = 'step_col_'+@step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query,

```
DECLARE @COL VARCHAR(50) = 'step_col_'+@step
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variables like this to form a dynamic sql query

```
DECLARE @step VARCHAR(25) = '15';
DECLARE @COL VARCHAR(50) = 'step_col_'+@step
exec ('UPDATE table_tblName SET '+@COL+'=<some value> WHERE <condition>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @step VARCHAR(25) = '15';
 DECLARE @COL VARCHAR(50) = 'step_col_'+@step;
 DECLARE @String VARCHAR(500) = ''
 SET @String = 'UPDATE table_tblName SET '''+@COL+''' = <some value> WHERE  
 <condition>' 
 EXEC (@String)
```

Comment: Consider adding a brief explanation of how/why the above helps solve the problem, to help others. From [Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15432908).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @step VARCHAR(25) = '15';
DECLARE @COL VARCHAR(50) 
SET @COL = 'step_col'+@step;

UPDATE table_tblName SET @COL=<some value> WHERE <condition>
```