# Mapping dynamic column names in SQL Server where dynamic variable integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-columns

As mentioned in this link [Mapping dynamic column names in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624480/mapping-dynamic-column-names-in-sql-server)

I want to generate column names like col_1,col_2... .The parameter `@num` is of integer type.

I have query as follows:

```
DECLARE @num int = 15;
DECLARE @COL VARCHAR(50) = col_@step;

UPDATE table_tblName 
SET @COL = <some value> 
WHERE <condition>
```

Comment: You can use CAST function to convert it to varchar then add, have you tried that?

Comment: I tried . It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This update statement can't work as it is. 
You can't parameterized identifiers in Sql.

When you write something like this:

```
UPDATE table_tblName SET @COL=<some value> WHERE <condition>,
```

What happens is that Sql Server threat it as two different statements:

```
UPDATE table_tblName
```

And

```
SET @COL=<some value> WHERE <condition>
```

Since the update statement does not contain the `SET` clause, it's basically a no-op.

To be able to parameterize identifiers you must use dynamic sql -

```
DECLARE @num int = 15;
DECLARE @COL VARCHAR(50) = col_ + @step;
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(200) = 'UPDATE table_tblName SET ' + @COL + '=<some value> WHERE <condition>'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

[See for yourself on rextester](http://rextester.com/VTRX60421)

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: Thanks for the help !